# iOS7 - Changing the position of a red minus button in UITableView in Edit mode

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I want to change the position of a red minus button in a UITableViewCell in Edit mode on iOS7.  I achieve it through by using the following code it's working fine.

```
for (UIView *view in cell.subviews) {

    for (UIView *subView in view.subviews) {

        if ([NSStringFromClass([subView class]) isEqualToString:@"UITableViewCellEditControl"]) {

            for (UIImageView *imageView in subView.subviews) {

                [subView.layer setMasksToBounds:NO];
                imageView.frame = CGRectOffset(imageView.frame, 0, -10);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But, I am facing problem on, it applicable for all the rows expect the 1st row. Please provide your suggestion to overcome this issue.

Comment: Where do you have this code?

Comment: I have the code in, - (void)didTransitionToState:(UITableViewCellStateMask)state;

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are doing thing in the code of a custom cell class. Since a cell doesn't know it's own `indexPath` (and it shouldn't) then I would suggest adding a `BOOL` property to your cell class. Set the property in the table view controller's `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method. Then the cell uses the value of the property to decide whether to adjust the button or not.

BTW - your code is fragile and could easily stop working if Apple changes the internal layout of a table cell (like that have in the past).

Comment: Thanks for ur response. Even I tried it in, - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath; But, same result.

Comment: Tried what? You added the property to your cell class and update your code above to only adjust the frame if the property is set? And you properly set the property in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method?

Comment: Thanks for ur suggestion and response. There is no need to have a bool variable. I found the solution, if we the above code in the UITableViewCell subclass layoutSubviews. We can achieve it.